# How to count repetition of characters in a word . Flex

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, lexer

I'm trying to count the repetition of characters in a word by flex and bison.

I don't know how to do that. Any help?

Comment: It's quite possible that I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you can't find a,way to express yourself more clearly in English, you could try adding some example inputs and outputs. (At least four examples, please, covering different possibilities.) But if I do understand, then this is not the sort of thing Bison and Flex are designed to do, and tou should find more appropriate tools.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode for counting letters in word, this might help?
Accepts a word or string and returns the count of each letter

```
def countChars(word){

   let charDict = {}

   for character in word:
      if character not in charDict
         charDict[character] = 1
      else
         charDict[character]++
   return charDict
}
```